# PHP MSSQL extension not loaded in xampp

Tags: php

I am trying to connect SQL server via php in XAMPP.

PHP MSSQL extension not loaded

I have it running in XAMPP 1.7.4 on Windows 7.

I am using PHP 5.3.5.

I hve download the php_mssql.dll and placed in php extension folder and i have also changed the php.ini file like follows.

> extension=php_mssql.dll

Now I restarting apache service. it is displaying two alert as

> 1. The Program can't start because php4ts.dll is missing from your computer.
> 2. The startup: unable to load dynamic libary

Comment: It requires `php4ts.dll`. Sounds to me like you loaded a MSSQL extension for PHP4 not PHP5. You probably only have the `php5ts.dll` in your directory. -- May try it hiere? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx#Using_the_SQLSRV_Driver

Comment: Have you tried configuring php.ini with a location of the file starting from the "root"?

Comment: Yes... I have configured php.ini.

Comment: @Smamatti: Yes. But it shows like that